# Windows Phone 8.1 - Way to check what listview item was clicked

Tags: click, windows-phone-8.1, listviewitem

Want to know how to check what listview item was clicked. I want to navigate to different pages depending on which listviewitem was clicked.

My XAML is like this:

```
<Page


x:Class="wp8.Pages.RegistrationFinalStagePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:wp8.Pages"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <Grid Margin="15,0,15,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="ListView1" Grid.Row="1" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListViewItem x:Name="ListViewItem1">
                    <TextBlock Text="Page 1"/>
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem x:Name="ListViewItem2">
                    <TextBlock Text="Page 2"/>
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem x:Name="ListViewItem3">
                    <TextBlock Text="Page 3"/>
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem x:Name="ListViewItem4">
                    <TextBlock Text="Page 4"/>
            </ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Easy - just add a SelectionChanged="myselectionchangedmethod" to your ListView parameters

Answer (score 2):

Read this, you can handle `SelectionChanged` event in this circumstance.

[SelectionChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-CN/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx)